# Transparency for overlapping views

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, alpha

I have two views partially overlapping each other. They are both children of the same superview but don't have parent-child relationship between each other.

Initialy viewA.alpha=1 and viewB.alpa=0 and then gradually I increase viewB.alpha which for some reason causes viewA to become more and more transparent though its alpha is still 1.

How to change transparency for one of the overlapping views without affecting the others visually?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: i would bet that ViewA is not more transprent but increasing alpha makes ViewB stronger. Can you provide some pictures? Or maybe movie with transition recorded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue turned out to be completely unrelated to this. I was instantiating the same view twice from a XIB file and this for some reason caused the problems.